# Confusion with making multiple boards based on tic tac toe outcomes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently in a course and I am working on a tic tac toe AI project. I am working on the result function where it would take possible outcomes of unplayed spaces from a set() and it would print a board for each tuple (i,j), which would be one tuple of the entire set, i for row, j for cell.
I was able to deep copy the board, and also make a variable which contains the possible outcomes of the board through my actions definition. I am having trouble with taking each and every tuple from my action set() and making a board for each tuple.

This is currently what I tried so far which is returning only one board with all the empty spaces filled, which I don't want. I want multiple boards which only fill one space out of the entire set:

```
def result(board, action):
    #making a set variable with the actions definition which prints possible outcomes
    action = actions(board)
   
    
    #change board depending on action
    for i,j in action:
        if player(board) == X:
            board[i][j] = X
        else:
            board[i][j] = O
        
    return board
```

This is the code for the action set from the actions definition

```
action = actions(board)
```

Please do not give me the real answer, I just need help and a boost in order to be able to output multiple boards, be it a system, built-in function, etc.

Comment: Still unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Quite a lot of info is missing. For instance, what does `player(board)` do? In fact, what is `board` exactly? Also, you have `for x in action` in the code snippet, but the `x` variable is not used again .

Comment: Yeah the X variable is a little confusing. The board is a variable which contains another definition called initial_state(), which is an empty board, but actually this board is the one that is used in the tic tac toe game. The function needs the input of a board, and a set of actions, then it will return all the boards of all those actions. Player(board) is the player function which determines if the player is X or O, I already completed that function.

Comment: Also @FanchenBao I removed the for x in action statement and whatever is left is the code that fills all of the empty spaces in the board.

Comment: Could you please update your code snippet? In fact, could you share more of your code so that we can run it on our machine and replicate the problem you have?

Comment: The indentation of your code is not valid. This is a basic requirement for Python code.

Comment: I changed it to the better version. This is the real problem. This is the code that is returning only one board.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `result()` function take the `board` (a 2 by 2 array) and just 1 `action` (given as a tuple `(i, j)` where `i` is the row on `board`, `j` is the column on `board`) as arguments, all you have to do is make a copy of the given `board`, play that move aka `action` i.e return a copy of the `board` with the `action`/move applied.

You can use the `player()` function to determine which player is to play.

For others you can find the specifications here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/ai/2020/projects/0/tictactoe/#understanding

Comment: Hi, but in order to get an individual action, and also in order to return a board for all the (i,j) actions, i needed to make a variable with the actions so its one set that i can change. The problem is getting an individual (i,j) action from the set and making a board for it, then repeating the same process until everything is done.

Comment: Like I said, that action argument its just one (1) action, not many, just one action (i, j).